# Confusion regarding component JUMPER-PAD-3-2OF3_NC_BY_TRACE

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, components, open-hardware, nrf51822

I am working on deploying a open source hardware project.In the list of components, they have mentioned one of the components as PAD-JUMPER-3-2OF3_NC_BY_TRACE_YES_SILK_FULL_BOX with value     JUMPER-PAD-3-2OF3_NC_BY_TRACE.I tried to search on net but not able to figure out what is this.Since, I am maths major not electrical engineering, so I have hard time in figuring this.
Please help me to figure out what is this and if possible how can  I make arrangement for this.Thank you.

Comment: Googling for "jumper pad", "pcb trace", "silk mask" and reading something about PCB design and production would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really a component at all. It's a solder jumper -- the component footprint forms three contacts, two of which are connected together by a trace. To change the jumper, it's possible to cut the trace between two of the contacts with a knife and drop a bit of solder on the other two to connect them.

The picture below shows what these look like on a circuit board. The two bits with the arrows pointing to them (ignore the instructions) are solder jumpers, with the top two contacts connected together by default.

[image]